# Linked server adding user SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recently moved a database from 2008 across to a new cluster server 2012.  I am now trying to create the linked server.  I have managed to add the linked server fine but when I try to add the user

```
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname='Server',
@useself='false', 
@locallogin = NULL,
@rmtuser='domain\user', 
@rmtpassword='password'
```

This is the error it produces

```
Msg 33096, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, Line 91
A generic failure occurred during Service Master Key encryption or decryption.
Msg 15185, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, Line 98
There is no remote user 'domain\user' mapped to local user '(null)' from the remote   server 'server'.
```

I have tried to backup the master service key from the 2008 database and tried to restore it, but I get the following

The current master key cannot be decrypted. If this is a database master key, you      should attempt to open it in the session before performing this operation. The FORCE option can be used to ignore this error and continue the operation but the data encrypted by the old master key will be lost.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this happens?